# How to set QGIS language other then OS

Tags: qgis, windows-7, internationalization

I have windows 7 in Arabic. Now I dowloaded QGIS 2.14.3-2 in French. 
But when I installed it shows Arabic menu/tools... 
How can I change the menu language to French?

Answer (score 5):

QGIS will use you system language by default. You can change this under Settings - Options - Tab Locale - Override system locale and choose another.